# Find and replace in atom with regex

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have bought theme that includes too many things like this:

```
$(".search-toggle").click(function() { ...
```

However the function wont get fired since I am using AngularJS components and the actual `search-toggle` class is found in a nested page.
The only way to reach it and make it fired is like that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.search-toggle', function() { ...
```

As I said there tons of such things and I either do not find efficient and fast way to switch from the first method I wrote to the second.

Note: I do not know the actual name of the required class - thats why I need regex in here so it will be applied for all of such cases.

Just for that example I have used `search-toggle`

I only found to make it manually but it would take lot of time - and maybe I face such a thing again in the next theme I will buy.

If you know something or maybe know some other fix for this that could be just awesome. Maybe a plugin for Atom.

I have tried find at Google but nothing founds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in Atom:

Make sure to enable the RegEx button (red arrow), then search for a RegEx with capture group of the CSS selector and replace it with whatever you want (`$1` corresponds to the first captured group).

[image]

The image above shows how you'd do it in your case.

Search Pattern: `\$\("(.*)"\)\.click\(`
Replace with: `$(document).on('click', '$1',`

Replace all and you'll get what you asked for ;)